# Overloading and Template Combined

Tags: c++

Below code made me confused:

1. I was expecting `operator+<int>` to give compilation time error, as operator overloading mandates at least one non-intrinsic type. If I try `int operator+(int i, int j)` it fails. But it did not create any problem, why?
2. If I call `2+3` does it not call `operator+`, I have to do explicitly `operator+<int>`?
3. Is there a better way, other then writing `operator+<int>` to call my definition of `operator+`?
4. Is there a place which i can refer, which explains it better?

NOTE: I used "Sun C++ 5.10"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T operator+(T i, T j)
{
        return i+j;
}

int main()
{
        cout<<2+3;
        cout<<operator+<int>(2,3);
        cout<<endl;
}
```

The output is as below,

```
bash-2.03$ ./a.out

55
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here.  You're aware that you can't create a function `operator+(int, int)`, and you've created a function `operator+<int>(int, int)`, which isn't the same thing...

Comment: operator+<int> is instantiating a template. So i thought if operator+(int, int) is not allowed then operator+<int>(int, int) also should not be allowed. As templates are resolved at compile time itself.

Comment: I had a print statement in the operator+ to see if it is called. That is how i came to the conclusion of 2).

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to the question is relatively simple: it is a compiler error! The relevant quote is over.oper paragraph 6, first sentence (of C++2011):

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration.

I tested your code with current versions of EDG's frontend, g++, and clang++ and they all, correctly, reject the code.

Comment: Is it legal to write a template for an operator function that appears to allow instantiation with types that aren't user defined types? In this case, is it just attempt to explicitly instantiate the template for `int` that is invalid or is the template declaration itself invalid?

Comment: That Is how it should have behaved. Perhaps sunStudio10 doesnot support this. I am sure declaring template like this will be allowed but compiler will complain, which is how it should be.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: you can write templates which look as if they can be instantiated, e.g. the operator above. However, the corresponding instantiation shall fail or not be considered (i.e. the compiler won't try to instantiate the operator).